# CiviCRM contribution page with authorize.net test payment always throws invalid login credentials

Tags: php, authorize.net, civicrm

I have setup the contribution page in civicrm with recurring payment. For payment processor I'm using authorize.net payment gateway. I entered correct API login ID, Transaction key, site url(https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll) for test payment also(Please refer this link: https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A415&pmv=print&impressions=false). I'm getting error message like

> Payment Processor Error message 2: 13 (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID
>   or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

even though I given correct credentials. Please help where I'm missing.

Note: I change my authorize.net account in test mode.

Comment: Are you testing in the sandbox or in production?  If you want to test in the sandbox, the correct endpoint is https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll and you should leave the sandbox in live mode.

Comment: I'm testing in sandbox. I also checked with test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll. but no luck.

Comment: What error is returned when you use 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'

Comment: same error as I mentioned above

Comment: I would suggest logging into the Sandbox and generating a new key.  While you are there, make sure your sandbox is in Live mode as well.

Comment: @rhldr Thanks for the reply. I generated the key several times and also I tested the account with live mode as well as test mode. no luck yet :( anyway I will try some other possibility also If I get any solution I will post it here.